# ArrayList<String> in Java, [€14,€55,€500]

Tags: java, webdriver

I have a list of webElement stored in an `ArrayList` of strings as below:

```
ArrayList<String> prints out [€300, €34, €56]
```

How do i remove the € sign?. 
I have tried `remove()` and other method but they won't work. Its an `ArrayList` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate through your list and use `String::replaceAll`

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList <String>();
    list.add("$123");
    list.add("$345");
    list.add("12345");

    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^\\$", ""));
    }
```

If you want to update the value in the `List` you can use `List::set`

Comment: Thanks for your help. this works perfectly. but what if I have something like [€1,000 , €500, €4,500, €60] how do i  remove the comma between the 1,000? so i want to have 1000 returned instead of 1,000.

Comment: You can chain `replaceAll`  e.g. `s.replaceAll("^\\$", "").replaceAll(",", "")`

Comment: You don't put .s after the first replaceAll

Answer (score 1):

It is not really clear what do you want. A new list with trimmed elements, just printing the elements w/o the Euro sign or something else? Is the Euro at the beginning of any element, can it occur multiple times? Etc... Here is just an idea:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("€14", "€55", "€500");
System.out.println(list);

List<String> trimmedList =
    list.
        stream().
        map(s -> s.startsWith("€") ? s.substring(1) : s).
        collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(trimmedList);
```

It prints:

```
[€14, €55, €500]
[14, 55, 500]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this regex,

```
  List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
  myList.add("$14");
  myList.add("$55");
  myList.add("$500");
  System.out.println(myList);
   for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
     myList.set(i, myList.get(i).replaceAll("^[^\\d]+", ""));
  }
  System.out.println(myList);
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gdnIOH/1)

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate through the elements and just cut off the first character (assuming the euro sign is in every single one)

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
...
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    myList.set(i,myList.get(i).substring(1));
}
```

Alternative solution in the event that the first character is not always the euro symbol.

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
...
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    myList.set(i,myList.get(i).replace((char)8364,(char)0));
}
```

Comment: what happens if the first char is not euro ?

Comment: The way he asked the question, I'm assuming that it always is. I have no reason to believe otherwise

Comment: Never trust what people say ;-)

Comment: `.replace((char)8364,(char)0));` did you test this ?

Comment: Yes I tested it and it worked. Do you have an issue with something in it??

Comment: Yes, after doing `list.set (i++, s.replace((char)8364,(char)0));` when I print it out `System.out.println(list);` I get simply `[` and nothing more

Comment: my code doesn't have a i++ or use s for the replace. if you use the code i wrote it works :-D

Answer (score 0):

you can use `replaceAll("^\\$", "")` on your `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this using Java 8 stream api.

```
List<String> prices = Arrays.asList("€300", "€34", "€56");
prices = prices.stream().map(s -> s.substring(1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(prices); // [300, 34, 56]
```

Comment: You could add some explanatory text, for example which minimum Java version is needed to compile this

Comment: Please explain your code, though is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your price list and replace the euro sign like :

```
for (String price : prices) {
        price.replaceAll("^\\$", "");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code works as per your requirement.

```
  List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
  myList.add("#14");
  myList.add("#55");
  myList.add("#500");
  System.out.println(myList);
  for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
      myList.set(i,myList.get(i).substring(1));
  }
  System.out.println(myList);
```

Output : 
[#14, #55, #500]
[14, 55, 500]

Comment: it is generally frowned upon to post code only answers